# Connect Django with existing remote MySQL schema

Tags: django, mysql-python

Im trying the get data from an *existing* remote MySQL table with raw SQL in Django. In other words I do not have to create tables (models in Django) - just read data in a table in a 1st step.

The following class is working on the localhost

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(20)
    last_name = models.CharField(20)

    for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
     print(p)
```

The result:

John Smith

Jane Jones

How can I define a class or function to get data out of an existing database.table, based on raw SQL, without generating first a class for creating the table ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Integrating Django with a legacy database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: Why don't you want to generate a model class?

Comment: @DanielRoseman correct, I do no want to creat a model class.....

Comment: @helb great.. . Thank for the hint. I checked this documentation but in the chapter ...raw SQL..... thanks!